# Why does Heroku re-compile my assets after the application has been idle for a while?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

In production (on Heroku), shouldn't the assets be compiled on bootup one time, and then never compiled again?

```
/production.rb
config.serve_static_assets = false
config.assets.compress = true
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = true
```

When someone doesnt hit my application for a while things go idle, and it seems that the assets are re-compiled when that new, fresh request comes in???

Any idea what im doing wrong?

Comment: That's a good question. I realise that it happens a lot to apps which do not have any traffic. I have a application that has very low traffic and the way i went around it was to cache the home page of the app. I might be doing it wrong but seems to make a huge difference.

Comment: Are you on the Cedar stack? Is it showing in your log that the assets are recompiling? Or is it just taking a long time?

Comment: Cedar stack, and it is showing the assets re-compiling if I havent hit the site for a while, and the first request causes a timeout cause it takes longer than 30 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Heroku, if your application is idle for an hour, the dynos will go into standby. That's why when you revisit your application it takes a bit to load the first time. You mention "bootup" time - that's exactly what's happening once your dynos reboot, **your instance does not continuously run once you push.**

When the dynos are coming back to life, your assets will need to precompile, since you have `config.assets.compile` set to false. This behavior really isn't out of the ordinary.

If you want to avoid that, you can set a cron job to `curl` your heroku instance every half hour.

Comment: i like the idea of a cron job every hour. Seems cleaner than what i am doing at the moment

Comment: @Vezu might be safe to do with a period of slightly **less** than one hour. Just because you don't want the dyno's to idle. Truth be told this is pretty unethical, since the dynos go idle *for a reason*.

Comment: They on off for a reason but i think they affect startup apps.  I used Rails just for the JSON data which i then use on a iphone app.

Comment: thanks.  Normally it wouldn't be a problem but that first request that comes in causes a timeout on our application.

Comment: That's annoying. Just so you're aware if the product you're building is ready for the spotlight, a paid plan on heroku prevents dynos from idling - that is, if you stick with heroku.