# Slow Asset Loading via Rails 3.2.12 + Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cdn, assets

I have an application deployed to Heroku using Rails 3.2.12 and am experiencing a lot of slowness - sometimes even fails - while trying to load some of the compiled assets. I checked that using Firebug's Network panel and checking my NewRelic reports. This is also happening in a customer application.

I tried deploying the assets to CloudFront but I'm using the FontAwesome icon set and Firefox isn't displaying those correctly due to a CORS issue - which I haven't been able to solve properly with any library or technique described so far. Here's a summary of what I've tried:

- Caching using Rack::Cache, Dalli and MemCachier: helps a little, but doesn't solve the problem.
- Using Rack::Deflater to compress the assets: same, helps but still doesn't solve the issue.
- Using Cloudfront: breaks custom fonts on Firefox.
- Using Cloudfront with rack-cors / before_filter to insert CORS headers / custom middleware to insert CORS headers: nothing. I can check with curl that proper CORS headers are being served but...no success.
- Using S3 and asset_sync: doesn't work. No assets served.
- Using font_assets: doesn't work, same problem as using Cloudfront directly.
- Using a proc on the asset_host configuration to serve fonts locally and everything else from the CDN: breaks the assets:precompile task.

So, has anyone been experiencing similar issues or has any idea how to fix this?

Cheers!

Comment: Is it possible it is because the assets are having to be compiled by multiple load-balanced VMs on the Heroku side? (So, there is some upfront cost of asset compilation after which loading would be much faster?) Or are assets being precompiled? e.g. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3x-asset-pipeline-cedar

Comment: Note: ignore what I said about VMs- a stab in the dark because I'm not familiar with how Heroku does dynos, but note that Heroku may recompile assets if the application is idle for a while: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10871813/178651

Comment: Gary, thanks for your input but I don't think this is the issue as both apps are never idle - they got a constant influx of traffic all day.

Comment: You said was compiled, but you doing the first method (precompiling) mentioned in link in my first comment? e.g. `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`. That or logging whats going on Sprockets might be a good idea to rule out compilation slowness. If it isn't that, are you looking at the log of the time to handle the request by Rack- is that slow (i.e. is it an issue within Rails or outside of Rails)? Just trying to help us determine where the bottleneck(s) are.